# Rails: how to customize app-wide behaviors when running a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rake task that performs activities that receives flags from the user on runtime. This task:

1. Runs methods across multiple models.
2. Changes settings that every model needs to know, almost like setting or changing an app-wide constant.

The task is invoked with something like:

```
rake "mytask:run[arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]"
```

I would like to be able to change variables that every class references based on these args. Passing these args back and forth among all these methods is doable but it feels very clunky in this situation. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you need a table to store these config variables. So it might be called `configs`, and it might have a column called `arg_name` and another column called `arg_value`.

Then you will set the values in the rake task and reference the values in the other models. It's not the 'canonical' rails model behaviour, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with this approach.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This doesn't solve it because these flags I referred to are temporary settings that are only needed for each rake task run. It seems way over the top to use a database table when something related to variables would work (global variables/env variables etc).

Comment: OK, yes, I didn't understand the vars only persist for the duration of the Rake task. So it seems as if you have your solution... env vars